# Netbeans 8.1 + PostgreSQL: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

Tags: postgresql, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I'm trying to execute SQL to create stored function and receive this error (1st one among others):

```
Error code 0, SQL state 42601: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
    DECLARE
      ret_val varchar"
  Position: 98
Line 1, column 5
```

google gives many notes for *other* tools saying that the problem is in client driver, but i could not find the hint how to fix this specifically in NetBeans. My environment is:

- Netbeans 8.1
- Target DB server - PostgreSQL 9.5 beta 2
- JDBC drivers (tested with both):

  - The one bundled with Netbeans: postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
  - The fresh one downloaded from postgres site: postgresql-9.4-1204.jdbc42.jar

SQL (runs OK in all SQL-runner apps except Netbeans, for example PgAdminIII):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(IN arg varchar)
  RETURNS varchar 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  ret_val varchar;
BEGIN
  select concat(arg, ' result') into ret_val;
  return ret_val;
END $$;

select test('aaa')
```

So - what has to be done with Netbeans to make it execute successfully?

Comment: NetBeans doesn't understand the dollar quoting and thus sends everything up to the very first `;` (which is at `ret_val varchar;`) to the server - which of course is an incomplete statement.

Comment: Yes, this what are saying for other tools. Is there cure for Netbeans?

Comment: I don't know. Although I exclusively use NetBeans for development I never use it to work with databases. So in short: you can't use NetBeans with dollar quoted functions. You would need to use standard SQL quoting (which is really annoying when you write complicated functions)